# XAML to Bitmap with high quality

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, bitmap

I'm trying to store a XAML in a bitmap file and print it to a pdf file.

My view shows the controls/text like this:

[image]

The pdf shows the created bitmap like this:

[image]

Here's the code on how I convert my XAML to a bitmap:

```
MyWindow view = new MyWindow();
view.Title = "SOME TEXT";
//add the table

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)view.ActualWidth, (int)view.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(view);
PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
//System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(pngImage.Frames[0]); //Clipboard still shows the pngImage in high quality!

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(pngImage.Frames[0]);
encoder.Save(stream);

Bitmap myCreatedBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

I'm using `System.Drawing.Printing` to print the pdf file. I'm assigning the bitmap in the EventHandler `PrintPageEventHandler` like this:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.bitmap, new Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.X, e.MarginBounds.Y, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height), new Rectangle(posX, posY, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

What's the reason for the blurry image or how can I convert my XAML to a bitmap with High Resolution and store it in a pdf?

Answer (score -1):

To convert XAML to PDF with high quality, try converting XAML to XPS and XPS to PDF, using Syncfusion [.NET PDF library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/).

Refer the below KB for converting XAML to PDF
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8083/how-to-convert-xaml-to-pdf-in-wpf-platform